# How to debug worker role which keeps recycling in Azure?

Tags: azure

I upgraded the Azure SDK and my app stopped working. I can't even deploy it because it keeps recycling. Unfortunately error messages provided by visual studio are too short. Deploying directly from management portal does not give much info either. I enabled verbose diagnostics but recorded error log entries do no seem to point to a solution.

I ran out of options. What else should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the diagnostics data as described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx, then follow through the troubleshooting workflows in that post to learn how to debug role startup failures.  In particular I think the scenario and instructions at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/10/03/troubleshooting-scenario-7-role-recycling.aspx will help.

For your scenario I suspect the issue is that you have a dependent DLL (ie. a base class library that implements your RoleEntryPoint class) that is using an older Microsoft.Azure.ServiceRuntime.dll and you are getting a version mismatch because your project is deploying the newer version of that DLL.

Comment: Turns out Azure SDK did not upgraded a project which depended on Azure Runtime and Diagnostics DLLs.